# Flutter - Opening store/market screen of a particular app inside the app

Tags: flutter

I would like to create a button inside my app when user taps it, it will open the market/store screen inside the app, not a redirect to official market/store app.

I do not know how to achieve it. Can someone help me to create it in Flutter.

Example: When you see an ad about downloading app in Reddit, if you press to download link it is opening an official market/store screen but there is no redirect to store/market app completely.

Comment: Show the code that you have tried.

Comment: Can you please be more explanative on what you exactly needed ?